# How to get all rows when still using a IF NOT NULL

Tags: sql

I have searched everywhere I could and can not find the solution to this (IF there is one). Also, I could be looking at this wrong (I am new into SQL).

I am trying to get the sum of gross sales where there is a cancellation date displayed. This code works just fine. My problem is: **is there a way to still get all rows (i.e. null rows) to display as 0 gross sales?** Am I looking at this completely wrong? Can someone help lead me in the right direction?

```
SELECT "Div Code", "Agent Name", SUM("Gross Sale")
FROM salessummary
WHERE "Cancel Date" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY "Div Code", "Agent Name";
```

This data output is 12 rows showing:

```
Div Code |  Agent Name  |  Gross Sale
  SC         John Smith      $120
  NC         Jane Smith      $130
  NC         Will Smith      $40
```

I want it to show all 30 rows (even if an agent has no cancellations):

```
Div Code |  Agent Name  |  Gross Sale  
  SC         John Smith      $120  
  *SC         Jada Smith      $0*  
  NC         Jane Smith      $130  
  NC         Will Smith      $40
```

The problem is that my sum of gross sales is based on if there is a cancellation date. This is what defines my data.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Simply remove the WHERE clause? Do `COALESCE(SUM("Gross Sale"),0)`.

Comment: `NULL` is a value for a scalar, not a property of rows.  You should provide sample data and desired results to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is that `Gross Sale` could have `NULL` values, I would recommend:

```
SELECT "Div Code", "Agent Name", COALESCE(SUM("Gross Sale"), 0) as "Gross Sale"
FROM salessummary
WHERE "Cancel Date" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY "Div Code", "Agent Name";
```

`COALESCE()` is the ANSI standard function that replaces a `NULL` values with the specified value.  Doing it after the `SUM()` means it is only called once -- a micro-optimization, but `NULL` values are ignored in the `SUM()`.

If you want all "div code"/"agent name" combos -- even those with no cancels -- use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT "Div Code", "Agent Name",
        SUM(CASE WHEN "Cancel Date" IS NOT NULL THEN "Gross Sale" ELSE 0 END) as "Gross Sale"
FROM salessummary
GROUP BY "Div Code", "Agent Name";
```

Comment: Thank you! The CASE WHEN worked like a charm. Thank you for also explaining the COALESCE, that helped me understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
 SUM(ISNULL("Gross Sale",0))
```

Comment: `ISNULL()` is product specific, and the question has no dbms specified. Use `COALESCE()` instead.